# What is the proper way to work with API Gateway AWSTask objects in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

I was directed to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44688027/what-is-the-proper-way-to-work-with-awstask-objects-in-swift) by one of the AWS iOS SDK developers over at Github ([link](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues/1389#issuecomment-480059767)) but I'm afraid I still don't understand how to access a passthrough Lambda response that is returned via API Gateway.

If you read [my iOS SDK usage question on this matter](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues/1389), you'll see that I'm able to successfully invoke my REST API via my simple iOS app. The Cloudwatch logs verify that Lambda is returning the correct response. But I don't know how to access those values in `result`.

Here's my code that invokes my REST API, which is based on the ["calc" REST API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integrating-api-with-aws-services-lambda.html) featured in the API Gateway documentation.

```
@IBAction func userInvokeApi(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("You clicked invoke api...")
    let client = SVTLambdaGateClient.default()
    client.calcGet(operand2: "3", _operator: "+", operand1: "5").continueWith{ (task: AWSTask?) -> AnyObject? in
        if let error = task?.error {
            print("Error occurred: \(error)")
            return nil
        }

        if let result = task?.result {
            // Do something with result
            print("The raw result is... \(result)")
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Yes, I realize all I'm doing is printing the address of `result`. Everything I've tried to print the values fails!

**UPDATE**
When I try `result.responseData` as recommended below, I get the following message:

```
Value of type 'Empty' has no member 'responseData'
```

`Empty` refers to the API Gateway model for passthrough responses from the Lambda function; it performs no transformation on the data.. just sends it on to the Client. Here's what my `Empty.swift` looks like:

```
import Foundation
import AWSCore

@objcMembers
public class Empty : AWSModel {

    public override static func jsonKeyPathsByPropertyKey() -> [AnyHashable : Any]!{
        var params:[AnyHashable : Any] = [:]

        return params
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: I believe it's in `responseData`. Try `print(String(data: result.responseData!, encoding: .utf8)!)` Of course, don't force unwrap those optionals in production code.

Comment: Geez, I really wish that would work. But Xcode tells me it's an error with this message: `Value of type Empty has no member responseData`. The API Gateway model in my case is called Empty, which basically does nothing to the response from the Lambda function... thus it's passthrough. I'll add some details above about the Empty.swift file that was generated as part of my API Gateway iOS Swift SDK.

Comment: In fact, that's pretty much the error I see when I try all reasonable attempts at accessing what I know the Lambda function to be returning: `Value of type 'Empty' has no member '<take-your-pick>'`